# React Native changing screen through header button

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {/* <LeftSideMenu /> */}
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          style={styles.title}
          options={{
            title: 'HOME',
            headerTintColor: Colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerRight: () => (
              <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')} title="Profile" />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

I want to change screen through the right header button

In the headerRight how can it changing screen from Home to Profile?

Now it  comes up with error: Can't find variable: navigation

Answer (score 2):

you can use useNavigation hook for this purpose.

```
import { useNavigation, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

in your component just create hook and use like this.

```
    const navigation = useNavigation();
   <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate('Confirm'));
        }}>
        
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is my example to achieve this kind of situation.

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="MyOrders"
        component={MyOrderScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
          title: 'My Orders',
          headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        }}
      />
```

Here i am creating screens in my stack and using header in separate component.

```
const HeaderRight = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginRight: 10
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate('Chats'));
        }}
      >
        
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access navigation with minimal code changes by simply passing a function to the options prop like so.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {/* <LeftSideMenu /> */}
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          style={styles.title}
          options={({navigation}) => ({ // only change
            title: 'HOME',
            headerTintColor: Colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            headerRight: () => (
              <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')} title="Profile" />
            ),
          })}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```